# Special character in string path causes an error. Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell script that gets the Java environment variable within the PATH which could be as follows:

```
$java = (Get-Command java | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Source).toString()
```

Outputs: $java = C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0\bin\java.exe

Then, I set the JAVA_HOME env variable by removing the \bin\java.exe path

```
$env:JAVA_HOME = "$java" -replace "\\bin\\java\.exe",""
```

And call a .bat script.

The main problem is that I get an error due to the parenthesis in (x86) within the .bat script:

**\Java\jdk1.8.0 was unexpected at this time.**

If I change the java path to Program Files (without any parenthesis) everything works fine. So I have been trying to escape special characters in the -replace method but nothing seems to be working.

```
$env:JAVA_HOME = "$java" -replace "\\bin\\java\.exe","" -replace [regex]::Escape(')'), [regex]::Escape(')') -replace [regex]::Escape('('),[regex]::Escape('(')
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I will try the solution you are pointing but when I change the path to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\bin\java.exe the program runs fine and there's also a space between Program and Files

Comment: With a path containing spaces it most likely needs to be quoted in the environment variable value itself. PowerShell doesn't do this on its own and what you've written doesn't actually add quotes since it just formats a string. Try `$env:JAVA_HOME = '"' + $java.Replace('\bin\java.exe', '') + '"'` (as a bonus we avoid the nasty escaping we need for regexes).

Comment: What is your batch file actually doing? For testing purposes, can you reduce it to a single line (or at least less than half a dozen lines) that trigger the error, and add it to your question?

Comment: I would also say your powershell script is fine, please show the part of the batch where you use %JAVA_HOME%.

Comment: Problem is .bat file is given and the only error reference that I get is \Java\jdk1.8.0 was unexpected at this time. I'm also starting to think problem might be in the .bat file...